# Chrome linear gradient bugs when dealing with subpixels

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cross-browser, linear-gradients

So I've been trying to use Linear Gradient for design my webpage, but for some reason Chrome doesn't like when it has to deals with subpixels.

Take a look at the snippet below. It works perfectly in Firefox, but in Chrome appears a thin line in the middle that disappears if the width is not odd. Also it completely breaks on Edge.

Does anyone knows a way to fix this to work in all browsers? (besides making sure that the containers is even).

```css
div {
  width: 201px;
  height: 50px;
}
.arrow {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: none;
  background: linear-gradient(15deg, #f7f7f7 0, #f7f7f7 50%, #008f49 50%, #008f49 52%, rgba(255,0,0,0) 52%, rgba(255,0,0,0) 100%), linear-gradient(345deg, #f7f7f7 0, #f7f7f7 50%, #008f49 50%, #008f49 52%, rgba(255,0,0,0) 52%, rgba(255,0,0,0) 100%), #1b4376;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 50%, 100% 50%;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-size: 50% auto;
  min-height: 170px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
</div>
```

Comment: increase the width a little and make it 50.5% instead of 50% .. this is known and you cannot avoid it wtih gradient

Comment: @TemaniAfif will it make work with Edge? Currently it's completely broken in Edge/Safari.

Comment: Even then I do not know where to put the 50.5% to make it work.

Comment: it should be there `background-size: 50.5% auto;` and I don't know about edge/safari I don't have those browser .. can you share a screen of those broken one?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/yR1QY4W

Comment: I think they don't understand the `background-size` auto. Putting a `100%` there fixed it

Comment: ah yes you should avoid the auto ... not all the broswer handle it the same way with gradient, always use values and 100% is somehow the auto value

Answer (score 0):

I'll post the answer by Temani Afif in the comment.

To fix the issue on Chrome, you need to have a fraction in the `background-size`. On my case, I used `50.06%` that I've found out to be the minimum, which rounds up to 50.1%. On my case using larget values created a visible noise in the output.

As on how to fix on Safari/Edge, all I needed to do was to replace `auto` with `100%` in `background-size`.